# How can I read the Authorization Code for a user after they have logged into my .Net Core web application, so I can use it with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-sdks, asp.net-core-6.0

The code example below is one I have seen a number of times, its a way to initialize a Microsoft Graph client. The code example is pretty straightforward, with one exception. In the code example, there is a line that expects the Authorization code from the user. As a user is logging in, I can debug and see the authorization code, no problem. However, the code example below will go into a utility class, and this won't be accessed until after the user is logged into the app.

So, how can I read the Authorization code for a user, after they have logged into the app, and then use that Authorization code to initialize the Microsoft Graph client?

```
using Microsoft.Graph; 
using Azure.Identity;


var scopes = new[] { "https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/.default" };

// Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
// single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
var tenantId = "tenant id";

// Values from app registration
var clientId = "client id";
var clientSecret = "client secret";

// For authorization code flow, the user signs into the Microsoft
// identity platform, and the browser is redirected back to your app
// with an authorization code in the query parameters
var authorizationCode = "authorization code "; <---- This is the line. How?

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

// https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.authorizationcodecredential
var authCodeCredential = new AuthorizationCodeCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, authorizationCode, options);


var accessToken = await authCodeCredential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes) { });

Console.WriteLine(accessToken.Token);
  
//var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authCodeCredential, scopes);
```